# Typescript/JS recursive promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm learning Javascript and I am stuck using Promises.

I'm trying to make a tree like structure from API documentation, where a $ref key in the JSON is replaced with the API object that resides somewhere else in the file. This needs to happen fairly synchronous where I go through the keys of the API object, when I find a $ref it's looked up and replaced in the JSON.

e.g.

```
"apiStorageVersion": {
    "description": "...",
    "properties": {
      "apiVersion": {
        "description": "...",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "kind": {
        "description": "...",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/apiMetaData",
        "description": "..."
      },
      "spec": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/apiSpec",
        "description": "..."
      },
      "status": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/apiStatus",
        "description": "..."
      }
    }
}
```

I start of with this function that gets a list of API objects that I consider parents in a sense that these are more important objects in the API. **Definitions** is the content of the file and holds all the API objects.

```
function fillObjectTree(parents: string[]) {
    console.log(parents);
    Object.keys(definitions).map(apiTitle => {
        // if the apiTitle is part of the parents list than we process it
        if (parents.includes(apiTitle)) {
            // Read the children and see if any references are part of the parent
            let par = readChildren(definitions[apiTitle])
            par.then(function (vals) {
                // Do something with values
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Next step is reading the properties of this API object and looking for $ref keys.

```
function readChildren(definition: { properties: any; }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Get the properties of the definition
        let props = definition.properties;
        // Properties are not always present on an object.
        if (props) {
            Object.keys(props).map(propName => {
                Object.keys(props[propName]).map(elem => {
                    if (elem.includes("$ref")) {
                        // locationURL = the full url for the reference
                        let locationURL: string = props[propName][elem];
                        // returns the needed value for the URL based on the regex
                        let partialURL: string = locationURL.match('(?<=(\#\/.*\/)).*')[0];
                        readReference(partialURL).then((body) => {
                            console.log(body);
                            delete definition.properties[propName];
                            definition.properties[propName] = body;  
                        });
                    }
                })
            })
            resolve(definition);
        } else {
            resolve(definition);
        }
    });
}
```

When a reference is found a second function is called that looks in the current file for this object.

```
function readReference(apiTitle: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Check all the definitions and find a match
        Object.keys(definitions).map(apiDef => {
            if (apiTitle === apiDef) {
                readChildren(definitions[apiDef]).then((body) => {
                    resolve(body);
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

So what's going wrong?
Well the order of operations does not seem to match what I want to happen. The object is not replaced in the JSON and not waited for when executing. I rather not used await or async but keep it to baseline Promises if possible.

Comment: Some quick hint on general Promise usage: 1. never create a Promise with `new` unless you want to "promisify" some callback-based async function 2. use Promise chaining instead, meaning you should always `return` your promises especially inside `then` 3. to wait for a series of promises to complete (like in `.map`s) use `Promise.all(...list of promises...)`

Answer (score 1):

`readChildren` will execute synchronously until it gets to this block:

```
readReference(partialURL).then((body) => {
  console.log(body);
  delete definition.properties[propName];
  definition.properties[propName] = body;  
});
```

`readReference` will return a promise, so it gets the promise then schedules whatever is inside the `then` to happen at some time in then future. Then the function continues, eventually calling `resolve(definition);` and then falling out of the function. This happens BEFORE whatever is inside the then.

To make `resolve(definition);` happen after everything else, simply put it in the `then` block too.

Edit: the above solution doesn't handle the map.

Handling lists of asynchronous results:

```
const promises = list.map(element => {
  return someAsyncFunction(element);
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    ... do stuff with the results
  });
```

Btw, all of this get flattened out if you use the vastly superior async/await syntax. It becomes much easier to reason about the ordering.

Comment: Wouldn't that stop my loop? The thing I have is that there can be multiple references and I want to return the apiDef with all the references replaced.

Comment: Updated the answer.